# Javascript Array Shorthand

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I just wanted to know if there was a shorthand way of writing this code:

```
allJobs[0].style.display = 'none';
allJobs[1].style.display = 'none';
allJobs[3].style.display = 'none';
```

I tried this way but it only ever hides the last value not the ones before it:

```
allJobs[0, 1, 3].style.display = 'none';
```

Im cant really use the classic for loop solution i don't think because some of the array elements are skipped out and displayed.
Thanks.

**Edit:** 
I have more than 3 display nones i just wanted to make the question simple, im not that lazy to write 3 lines!

Comment: What's wrong with the first example? It's at least very clear.

Comment: I know but i have a whole lot of the display nones so i want a shorter way to write them! For future reference as well!

Comment: Is it always items 0,1, & 3 that you wish to hide or is there some other rule at play here?

Comment: @AdamAlexanderWilson: If you were using jQuery, you could just write `$('selector').hide()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
[0, 1, 3].forEach(function(d) {
    allJobs[d].style.display = 'none';
});
```

Though admittedly, having only three elements, this is not much shorter...

Comment: …or the same thing with a loop, yes.

Comment: IE8 and below don't support `forEach`, so if you do support those browsers, you'll need a polyfill.

Comment: Perfect! and i have more i just wanted to make the question clear, i actually tried this but i must of been a little off with the code

Answer (score 4):

While other examples will support newer browsers, this should work across the board:

```
var indexes = [0, 1, 3];

for(var i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
    allJobs[indexes[i]].style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Iterating over an array with `in`?

Comment: @Blender - The reason I say it's not a good idea is that, if you pass in something other than an array or an array with added properties, it will also include those keys in the loop.

Comment: ...or if something in the page has modified `Array.prototype`... using `in` to iterate an array is a bad idea.

Comment: @josh3736 - Removed the questionable use of in. Just makes it a little less pretty.

Comment: Also, don't you need to pass the value of each array element rather than the index to the `allJobs` accessor?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do this:

```
function setHidden() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) allJobs[arguments[i]].style.display = 'none';
}

setHidden(0, 1, 3);
```

This particular method avoids costly function invocation for each element (like `Array.forEach`).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative approach:

```
function setStyle(element, cssAttrib, cssValue) {
  element.style[cssAttrib] = cssValue;
}

var indexes = [ 0, 1, 3 ];
for ( var i = indexes.length-1; i > -1; i-- ) // Loop Backwards For Constant Comparison
{
  setStyle(allJobs[i], "display", "none");
}
```

Note that calling setStyle incurs a function invocation penalty similar to the forEach approach.  If performance is an issue you could consider inlining your style changes.

```
var indexes = [ 0, 1, 3 ];
for ( var i = indexes.length-1; i > -1; i-- ) // Loop Backwards For Constant Comparison
{
  allJobs[i].style.display = none;
}
```